# Numpy: Sort 3d array with varying datatypes into chronological order

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

[sample photo of .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pM2Y.jpg)
I'm loading in monthly temperature data from a folder full of `.txt` files. The datatypes of the four columns I'm trying to use are a date followed by 3 ints. (the three ints being max, min, average daily temperature)

The code below creates a 3D array with the first dimension being the numbered file in the folder.

For example `lines[255]` would Output

```
'2012-11-01' '80' '59' '69.5'
```

through

```
'2012-11-30' '79' '69' '74.0'
```

`lines[255][0]` would exclusively be

```
'2012-11-01' '80' '59' '69.5'
```

and for the sake of example `lines[255][0][0]` is just

```
'2012-11-01'
```

I am aware that it is difficult to sort by object type.
Is there an order I could use for the four data types to load the data in a way I could sort the array into chronological order?

```
 for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(folder_to_open)):
    try:
        vals = np.loadtxt("{}/{}".format(folder_to_open,file),
                            dtype=(object),
                            delimiter="\t",
                            skiprows=3,
                            usecols=np.arange(0,4),
                            encoding = 'unicode_escape',
                            )
        lines.append(vals)
        if i == 256:
            break
```

Comment: Will you please add a sample of your text file(s)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.